# tr:hover{} this code print on page but i want to work that when my mouse point on a particular tr background color will apply

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, css3

```
<apex:component controller="contactcloudcontroller">
<apex:form id="pgBlock">
 <apex:pageBlock>
     tr:hover{
            background-color: #87cefa;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 30px;
       }
    <table width="100%" style="font-size: 12pt; border: 1pt solid black;">
        <tr bgcolor="#87cefa">
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </tr>
          <apex:repeat value="{!clist}"  var="cont">
            <tr>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.firstname}" /></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.lastname}"/></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.email}"/></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.phone}" /></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.mailingstate}"/></td>
                  <td><apex:outputText value="{!cont.mailingCity}"/></td>
             </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>

     <apex:pageblockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton value="First Page" rerender="pgBlock" action="{!FirstPage}" disabled="{!prev}" immediate="true"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!Previous}" immediate="true" rerender="pgBlock" disabled="{!prev}" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!Next}" immediate="true" rerender="pgBlock" disabled="{!nxt}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Last Page" rerender="pgBlock" action="{!LastPage}" disabled="{!nxt}" immediate="true"/>

   </apex:pageblockButtons>
   </apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your style inside `<style>` tag

```
<style> 
tr:hover{
            background-color: #87cefa;
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 30px;
       }
</style>
```

---

I believe you need to provide id to your table.

So This css only apply for the table.

```
<table width="100%" style="font-size: 12pt; border: 1pt solid black;" id="tableId">
 //you content here
</table>
```

and you css will be like

```
 <style>
 #tableId tr:hover{
        background-color: #87cefa;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 30px;
   }
   </style>
```